# How to find a specific sound in the audio track if i have a sample?

Tags: audacity, sample, analysis, search

So i have this file which is all talking people and beep sounds. The beep sound is always the same and i need to mark every place where it plays. It would be great if it's possible to do with Audacity.
But i think i can only search for silence or sound above a certain dB level with it. Is there something i'm missing or do i need another app?

Comment: Sometimes, tasks like that are quicker to do manually than spend the time in trying to find something to do it for you. Imagine what it would have been like to do the task on tape, then think how much quicker it's going to be in Audacity ;)

Comment: This isn't an option - there are several 10hrs long recordings.

Comment: That is a rather complicated task - the only remotely related project I know of is a sound detection and identification project by Derek Hoiem, but that is in a far from functional stage unless you're willing to do some programming: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/dhoiem/projects/solar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no software that can do this for you automatically, however if the beep sounds is very distinguishable and it is possible for you to isolate its primary frequencies with an EQ, you may be able to make it drive a gate, which then in turn silence the track when there is no beep.

You then render a new wave file with this gated output and import that into same project, and use your existing search for silence/sound function to search for non silent parts on the new track.

Comment: That sounds interesting, gonna look into that, thanks.
I guess i should also mention that the beep is always separated from the speech. So it has a very distinctive waveform. Can i somehow search for matching waveform pieces?

Comment: IIRC Sound Forge has some sort peak search function like that, but it may just be glitch search. However if the wave is very distinctive like you say, the EQ masking -> gate trick should work - maybe you could post an example of a part with the beep in?

Comment: I'm not sure how do i upload audio here..
Where can i learn more about isolating frequencies with an EQ and doing that gate thing? Is it even doable in Audacity?

Comment: Just use sound cloud.  Yeah, Audacity should be okay for that. Do you have the beeping sample isolated too?

Comment: Well it's basically a Siri's sound. There are also other personal assistants used in this thing but only one for each record so it's the same sound all track long and we need to find every time it is played.